# JPA: How to merge two jpa results to one pagable

Tags: spring-boot, jpa, spring-data-jpa, jpql

I have two Queries:

**Query1(pagable) first datasource**

**Query2(pagable) second datasource**

I would like to do something like this

**Page results = merge(query1, query2)**

How i can do this in JPA ?

Answer (score 0):

Are both queries on the same entity? If so you can collect the content from both in a list (`List<T> content`) and build a new page object. Something as follows:

```
Page<T> mergedResult = new PageImpl(List<T> content);
```

https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/commons/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/domain/PageImpl.html